# Get Date/Time Workbook Was Opened

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some code that needs to check the date that a spreadsheet was opened. Not the date it was created, and not necessarily today's date--some users apparently leave the spreadsheet open for several days, and this code only runs when the workbook is printed.

Previously, I'd used this code:

```
Dim FileSystem as Object

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Debug.Print FileSystem.getFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name).DateCreated
```

That initially worked fine, but now I'm running into another problem. For some users it works fine--they are opening this spreadsheet through the version controlled server, which downloads a copy to a protected directory. In that case, the `.DateCreated` represents the date they pulled the copy from the server. But other users are opening the workbook by opening a link to the file on the server through Internet Explorer, which skips the protected directory. For those users the code doesn't work at all--opening the spreadsheet through the link and checking it's file path, I get the following:

```
debug.print ThisWorkbook.Path

Output: http://servername.com/serverfolder/
```

Unsurprisingly, `FileSystem.getFile` crashes when pointing it towards a web server instead of a filepath. I tried instead to use `ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")`, but the problem there is that it's giving me the date the workbook was originally created--in this case, all the way back in 2005. 
Is there any simple way to get the date and time the workbook was opened?

Is it stored anywhere at all?

Comment: I can't imagine it would be stored, but you could create a Public variable in a module, and then set it to `Now()` in the `Workbook_Open` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the end result of this, you could do something as simple as:

entering =now() into a cell then running a macro to copy and paste as values.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this, but looks like I'm out of luck. I wound up mixing your answer with @YowE3K's comment (ran code on `Workbook_Open` to store the value of `Now()`), but put it in a custom doc prop instead of a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using now() in the Workbook_Open event to store the datetime that the workbook was opened in one of the worksheets. This does make the assumption that no one will change the value.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Now()

End Sub
```